# Read similar properties in different variables from application.yaml in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, config

I have below config in application.yml file

```yaml
Apple:
      color:[red, green, white]
      based-city: [jammu:red, maharastra:green]

Banana:
        color:[red, green, yellow]
        based-city: [jammu:red, karnataka:green, nagpur:yellow]
```

I need to read above config in below class object.

```java
class fruit{
      List<String> color;
      Map<String, String> basedCity;
}
```

I want to read config by `@Value` like below.

```java
@Value("${Apple}")
fruit apple;

@Value("${Banana}")
fruit banana;
```

I tried this multiple times (this is replica as exact code I can not paste) but getting no placeholder found error. Ideal it should read the prop in corresponding object.

Please help me if you face this kind of issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A little bit off-topic: please try to follow standard naming conventions and start your class names with an upper case letter => `Fruit` would be better, at least for posting to SO.
The YAML format you posted is not valid, so is this due to the "replica", or is that original?

Comment: The map `based-city` should be written with curly brackets `{key:value}`

Comment: Cyberbrain: this is replica of my scenario and just typed in SO so might be indentation not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Spring does not support structured values with plain `@Value` annotations, but you can use something different, called [Type-safe Configuration Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties):

This allows for a full structured class to be injected with a single annotation - but you cannot exactly reuse the structure multiple times with different values. (The documentation mentions that you could also use that annotation I show below for `@Bean` annotated methods, but that didn't work for me - maybe because I used *application.yaml* with structured content like you wanted and not *application.properties* with all flat entries.)

Here is my example.

First the implementation of the structured configuration:

```java
package org.example.q77983205;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("basket")
public class Basket {
  private Fruit apple;
  private Fruit banana;
  private List<Fruit> others;

  public Fruit getApple() {
    return apple;
  }

  public void setApple(Fruit apple) {
    this.apple = apple;
  }

  public Fruit getBanana() {
    return banana;
  }

  public void setBanana(Fruit banana) {
    this.banana = banana;
  }

  public List<Fruit> getOthers() {
    return others;
  }

  public void setOthers(List<Fruit> others) {
    this.others = others;
  }

  static class Fruit {
    private List<String> color;
    private Map<String, String> basedCity;
  
    public List<String> getColor() {
      return color;
    }
  
    public void setColor(List<String> color) {
      this.color = color;
    }
  
    public Map<String, String> getBasedCity() {
      return basedCity;
    }
  
    public void setBasedCity(Map<String, String> basedCity) {
      this.basedCity = basedCity;
    }
  }
}
```

Then my *application.yml*

```yaml
basket:
  apple:
    color: [ red, green, white ]
    based-city: { jammu: 'red', maharastra: 'green' }
  banana:
    color: [ red, green, yellow ]
    based-city: { jammu: 'red', karnataka: 'green', nagpur: 'yellow' }
  others:
    - color: [ blue, pink ]
      based-city: { key: 'value' }
    - color: [ brown, purple ]
      based-city: { hello: 'world' }
```

And finally a test to prove it works and make it a minimal reproducible example:

```java
package org.example.q77983205;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@SpringBootTest
class BasketTest {
  @Autowired
  Basket basket;

  @Test
  void appleTest() {
    assertEquals(List.of("red", "green", "white"), basket.getApple().getColor());
    assertEquals(2, basket.getApple().getBasedCity().size());
    assertEquals("red", basket.getApple().getBasedCity().get("jammu"));
    assertEquals("green", basket.getApple().getBasedCity().get("maharastra"));
  }

  @Test
  void listTest() {
    List<Basket.Fruit> others = basket.getOthers();
    assertEquals(2, others.size());
    assertEquals(List.of("brown", "purple"), others.get(1).getColor());
    assertEquals(1, others.get(0).getBasedCity().size());
  }
}
```

An important finding for me was, that I needed to provide getters and setters in the config class, otherwise the injected object always was empty.

You could also use `record`s to make your code smaller (if you don't need to modify the config after injection), but for that, you need to add a `@Configuration` annotated class with an additional annotation `@EnableConfigurationProperties(Basket.class)` - with that you can spare the `@Component` annotation of the `Basket` class - whether it's a record or not (records don't allow that annotation at all).

**UPDATE:**
Per request of the OP I updated the code to also include lists of objects. Actually the solution is really easy, it's just a matter of how you specify a list in YAML. Your question already introduced on with square brackets `[]`, I added now another one with dashes `-` at the beginning of the indentation level.

So the main change you should look for is in *application.yml*.

Comment: Thanks for answer just 1 more change so instead of creating separate object if i want to inject list of object like List<fruit> so how can we do that.

Comment: @VarunBansal I extended my example for a list of custom objects `List<Fruit>`. (Your question and my first version already included `List<String>` )